# how to append a list to pandas data frame as new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I'm trying to create a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to record every transaction record.

Here is what I have created:

```
def create_blotter():
    blotter = []
    return blotter

def create_blotter_columns():
    columns = ['Buy|Sell', 'Ticker', 'Volume', 'PricePerShare', 'Timestamp', 'TotalCosts']
    return columns


class Ledger:

    _blotter = create_blotter()
    _blotter_columns = create_blotter_columns()

    def update_blotter(self, side, ticker, quantity, price, timestamp, transaction):
    columns = self._blotter_columns
    line = [side, ticker, quantity, price, timestamp, transaction]
    self._blotter.append(line)
    self._blotter = pd.DataFrame(self._blotter, columns=columns)
    self._blotter.sort_index(ascending=False)
    return self._blotter
```

The reason I did that way was that when I created both blotter and columns as follows, it would return tuples, thus I am unable to add new lines of lists to that.

```
def create_blotter_frame():
    blotter = []
    columns = ['Buy|Sell', 'Ticker', 'Volume', 'PricePerShare', 'Timestamp', 'TotalCosts']
    return blotter, columns
```

Anyway,so the first code works the first time, but it returns with error message:

> ```
> RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
>   result = result.union(other)
> ```

I can't understand how it works the first time, and the second time it returns such error. The list is supposed to be capable of any types of data.

My goal is to log all transaction records and aggregate them as `line` and append it to the `blotter` and display every record of transactions in the end.

The sample data is like this:

```
side = 'Buy'
ticker = 'AAPL'
quantity = 100
price = 100
timestamp = "2018-02-27 23:12:50"
transaction = 100000
```

And every transaction will create new values with timestamp.

Comment: can you provide some sample data? the data itself isn't important, but it's useful to check what types are present in your `df.index`.

Comment: @jpp I've added the samples but I am not sure if that'd be sufficient. I am basically changing the sample's values to check every time I think of new way to make this work. The index itself is the default numbers. I am wondering when it tries to add the second time, it adds to new column instead of as a new row.

Comment: can you paste `df.head().to_dict()` ?

Comment: `{'Buy|Sell': {0: 'sell', 1: 'Sell'},
 'PricePerShare': {0: 567, 1: 100},
 'Ticker': {0: 'ticker', 1: 'AAPL'},
 'Timestamp': {0: '11:11:11', 1: '2018-02-27 24:12:50'},
 'TotalCosts': {0: 123456, 1: 5555},
 'Volume': {0: 567, 1: 100}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Dataframe.append()`:

#### Code:

```
blotter.append(
    dict(zip(columns, (side, ticker, quantity, price, timestamp, transaction))),
    ignore_index=True).set_index('Timestamp').sort_index(ascending=False)
```

#### Test Code:

```
class Ledger:
    columns = ('Side', 'Ticker', 'Volume', 'PricePerShare',
               'Timestamp', 'TotalCosts')

    def __init__(self):
        self._blotter = pd.DataFrame([], columns=self.columns).set_index(
            'Timestamp')

    def update_blotter(self, side, ticker, quantity, price, timestamp,
                       transaction):
        self._blotter = self._blotter.append(
            dict(zip(self.columns, (
                side, ticker, quantity, price, timestamp, transaction))),
            ignore_index=True).set_index('Timestamp').sort_index(
            ascending=False)
        return self._blotter

    @property
    def blotter(self):
        return self._blotter

ledger = Ledger()
ledger.update_blotter(
    side='Buy',
    ticker='AAPL',
    quantity=100,
    price=100,
    timestamp="2018-02-27 23:12:50",
    transaction=100000,
)
print(ledger.blotter)
```

#### Results:

```
                    Side Ticker  Volume  PricePerShare  TotalCosts
Timestamp                                                         
2018-02-27 23:12:50  Buy   AAPL   100.0          100.0    100000.0
```

Comment: I tried earlier to use the pandas.Dataframe.append() but it wouldn't work if the dataframe already exists. I've never seen dict zip function before though. Thank you for sharing your insights!